# Maven transitive dependencies

Tags: maven-3

I have 3 maven projects: first - "A" with packaging jar, second - "B" packaging jar, third - "C" packaging jar. "C" depends on "B" as compile time dependency, "B" depends on "A" also as compile time dependency. Project "C" also uses classes from "A". So I have transitive dependency C -> B -> A. But when I try to build these projects maven failed with compilation error while compiling project C: it can't find classes from project "A" that is used in "C".

I thought that maven resolves transitive dependency. Why I get such an error?

Comment: This should work fine, so something is not correct. Does B compile fine?  Is the parent pom a multiple pom and define A, B and C as modules?  Are you using a test class of A in C?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maven *resolves* transitive dependencies, but will not (usually) automatically *build* them for you. You can get maven to do what you want by supplying the `--also-make/-am` flag along with the project list:

```
mvn -am -pl C clean install
```

This assumes that A, B, C are all modules of a shared parent, and you would be running the command above in the parent's directory.

Comment: when I run 'mvn clean install' on project C maven logs the order in which projects are processed(A, B, C), in the console I see succesfully processed A and B projects; so before project C starts processing, projects A artifacts are already in repository.

Comment: typo, I run `mvn clean install` on parent project of that 3 ptojects

Comment: @maks you'll need to post more details of the precise error message. Your scenario is the normal case for Maven; it should work. Maybe the versions are not consistent? If maven is building them in the right order then there is some other fault in your POMs.

Answer (score 0):

The failure of transitive dependency in Maven occurs due to many reason. You need to enable debugging option for that. 
I faced similar issue. I am using eclipse. To enable debug option for maven in eclipse: Windows->Preference->Maven->Tick mark Debug Output

Error in my project was:

```
[WARNING] The POM for mil-pop2:java-json:jar:1.0 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available: 4 problems were encountered while building the effective model for mil-pop2:java-json:1.0
[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.systemPath' for java-json.jar:java-json.jar:jar must specify an absolute path but is ${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/lib/java-json.jar @
```

The reason for failure in transitive dependency is the project in which we are dependent inherits the jar from custom path rather than local repository. Remove the custom path if you have provided.

Before :

```xml
<dependency>
<groupId>java-json</groupId>
<artifactId>java-json.jar</artifactId>
<version>1</version>
<scope>system</scope>
<systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/lib/java-json.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

After:

```xml
<dependency>
<groupId>org.json</groupId>
<artifactId>json</artifactId>
<version>20090211</version>
</dependency>
```

This solved my error.